# I cannot copy the file directly to extenal sdcard and sdcard/Android folder

Tags: android

I cannot copy the file directly to external SD card and `SD card/Android` folder.

Actually, the file is created but shows the size **0 bytes**.

In other folders of SD card, the file copies successfully.

It is Android kitkat 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

sdcard/Android is an restricted folder for system data, you should not be copying anything in that folder unless you have root permissions.

Comment: and file copied directly to sdcard(means not in any folder) also gives file with no content copied.what about that?

Comment: As I said, this issue could be because of root access not provided in your phone, even root of sdcard comes under root privileges if I am not wrong, if you have any rooted phone please try in that.